# Generate XML tags form XML attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I am having following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Types>
<Type ID="1A" type="Generic" BasicID="1a1">
<properties>
<property name="ID" value="1A" />
<property name="Name" value="ABC" />
<property name="Dept" value="DEF" />
</properties>
<relationships>
<relationship name = "Dependant1" value ="Father"/>          
<relationship name = "Dependant2" value ="Mother"/>
<relationship name = "Dependant3" value ="Spouse"/>
</relationships>
</Type>
</Types>
```

I want to convert it to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Types>
<ID>1A</ID>
<Name>ABC</Name>
<Dept>DEF</Dept>
<Dependant1>Father</Dependant1>
<Dependant1>Mother</Dependant1>
<Dependant1>Spouse</Dependant1>
</Types>
```

I am very new to XSLT please help me out of this.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The transformation of the elements is done with

```
<xsl:template match="property | relationship">
 <xsl:element name="{@name}">
   <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
 </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

then add

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//property | //relationship"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and you have the stylesheet.